# Upgrading to Gawk 4.0

Tags: package-management, compatibility

I am working on a project that has me using Gawk. I had been using Fedora 16 which uses Gawk 4.0 but have recently changed over to Xubuntu 11.10 and found out that Xubuntu runs an older version of gawk (3.1.8 I believe). There are probably 3 dozen different utilities that rely on Gawk in Xubuntu and I really don't want to break anything.

What are my options for running Gawk 4.0 in Xubuntu 3.1.8? Is there any way I can run some kind of isolated version of Gawk 4.0 that I can use for my project and still have Gawk 3.1 used by the system?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing gawk 4.0.1 or later from one of the two PPA's that have it:

1. https://launchpad.net/~dns/+archive/gnu
2. https://launchpad.net/~schot/+archive/gawk

There shouldn't be any problems with system utilities breaking due to using this newer version of gawk.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)